# Pointers in C programming language

Tags: c, pointers

I need little help, I have seen the following 2 codes on some facebook page.

Code 1:

```
/*this is fyn and will print knowledge*/ ‪ 
#‎include‬<stdio.h>
void choco(char *s)
{
    if(*s=='\0')
    return;
    printf("%c",*s);
    choco(++s);
}
main()
{
    choco("knowledge");
}
```

Code 2:

```
/*even this is fyn bt it wll print egdelon*/‪
#‎include‬<stdio.h>
void choco(char *s)
{
    if(*s=='\0')
    return;
    choco(++s);
    printf("%c",*s);
}
main()
{
    choco("knowledge");
}
```

Can someone explain me the output of both the C codes in detail. I'm bit confused.

Comment: It's a recursive function, but one is printing the current character first followed by the remaining characters, while the other is printing the remaining characters before the current character.

Comment: why the second one is printing the string in reverse order...without the first word?

Comment: The second one prints in reverse because it prints the subsequent characters before the current character. However, the code in both is a bit broken; "++s" should be replaced with "s+1", since this is not a loop, and so there is no need to mutate "s". The second one is screwed up because it is incrementing "s" before it is printing its current value, which is simply wrong.

Comment: to understand it better try it with a short string `"ab"` then follow the recursion with a pencil and a paper . Do consider to refer to one of the answers cited below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `choco("knowledge");` on both example calls the `chocho` function with a pointer to the first character of the string *knowledge*, 'k'. C-Strings created this way will always include a trailing byte '0', so string functions do know where the String ends.
- `if(*s=='\0') return;` skips if the end of the String is reached (0-byte, see above)
- `printf("%c",*s);` prints the character to which the pointer `s` is currently pointing to. `*s*` is used to retrieve the actual character from the pointer.
- `choco(++s);` calls choco with the pointer `s` increased by one, so it points to the next character of the string.

Using this information the first code example is quite straightforward. The function `choco` is called and prints the first character. It then lets the pointer point to the next character ('n') and calls itself with the updated pointer. This is repeated until the end of the String (0-byte) is reached.

In the second code example the function first calls itself using the next character, and prints the character when the call is returned. Thus the last character is printed first.

Consider the call `choco("abc");`:

1. choco is called with *s* pointing to *a*
2. on line 3 of choco, choco is called again with *s* pointing to *b*
3. on line 3 of choco, choco is called again with *s* pointing to *c*
4. on line 3 of choco, choco is called again with *s* pointing to to trailing '0'
5. choco returns because of the condition `if(*s=='\0')`
6. the choco execution of 3. continues to output *c*
7. the choco execution of 2. continues to output *b*
8. the choco execution of 1. continues to output *a*

I added some debug outputs to your second code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void choco(char *s){
    printf("choco was called with: %c\n", *s);
    if(*s=='\0'){
        printf("I return\n");
        return;
    }
    choco(s+1);
    printf("output: %c\n",*s);
}
int main()
{
    choco("knowledge");
}
```

this is what the output looks like:

```
choco was called with: k
choco was called with: n
choco was called with: o
choco was called with: w
choco was called with: l
choco was called with: e
choco was called with: d
choco was called with: g
choco was called with: e
choco was called with: 
I return
output: e
output: g
output: d
output: e
output: l
output: w
output: o
output: n
output: k
```

Comment: but in the code 2: %c is printing on one character. How all of the letters are printed. I think only the last letter must be printed because of choco(++s); and then the printf(); statement?

Comment: @user3742121 I added an example that might help you to understand my answer. Just ask, if there is still something that you don't understand

Comment: if it returns when it is pointed to null character. How does the printf(); statement have worked?

Comment: @user3742121 the function calls itself, so you have several *instances* of the function running (that's called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))). The last one is called with the zero byte and therefore does directly return. Each of the called functions prints exactly one character (in both versions). The only difference of Code1 and Code2 is the order in which they print the character and call the next function.

Comment: Hi. I need to chat with you. Can I have your fb profile URL?

Comment: @user3742121 please see my last edit

Answer (score 0):

let's try it with shorter string :

```
void choco(char *s)
{
    if(*s=='\0')
    return;
    choco(++s);
    printf("%c",*s);
}
main()
{
    choco("ab");
}
```

1. *s = 'a' :
    call(++s)
2. *s = 'b':
   call(++s)
3. *s = '\0':
   return to the result of step 2 of course

so `print b` and return to result of step1

so `print a`

then finish

** EDIT ** according to your comment 
let's try follow it here:

```
choco("ab") :

if('A' = '\0') return;
choco('B') -----------------> if('B'='\0') return;
                              choco('\0') -----------------> if('\0'='\0') return;
                              printf(B)    
printf(A)
```

Comment: if it returns when it is pointed to null character. How does the printf(); statement have worked? –

Comment: @user3742121 see the edit I guess it's clear now